# All 2D differentiable surfaces conformal to the euclidian metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, surfaces, conformal-geometry

Is it true that the metric of *any* continuous differentiable 2D surface is *locally conformal* to the *euclidian metric* ? (see equ. (2) below).  Can I state something like this in general ?  If so, what is the name of the theorem that gives a demonstration ?  If it's not general, what are the conditions to make this true ?
\begin{align}\tag{1}
ds^2 = g_{ij} \, dx^i \, dx^j &\equiv g_{11} \, dx^2 + g_{22} \, dy^2 + 2 \, g_{12} \, dx \, dy \\[12pt]
&= \Omega^2(u, v)(du^2 + dv^2). \tag{2} 
\end{align}
The original metric (in coordinates $x$, $y$) is positive definite.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates